# Determine Browser's Version

Tags: php, detection

How do I get the browser version?
I have done the browser detection part but every browser have different algorithm of its version release and its hard to get it. I already have looked in PHP's manual about get-browser function but every script seems out of my brain.

Comment: Why do you want to determine the browser's version?

Comment: Out of curiousity: Why do you want to? Is there some reason you need to know? If it's so you know what it can do, that's usually a bad idea; instead, use **feature detection**. Some useful ones [here](http://kangax.github.com/cft/) and [here](http://www.modernizr.com/). This future-proofs your code and makes it so you don't have to constantly update it as browser versions change.

Comment: I am making my own page which tells my system's detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any php code to detect the browser with version and operating system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142030/any-php-code-to-detect-the-browser-with-version-and-operating-system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it easily with [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser();
$version = $browser->version;
```

Comment: This community is for advanced user I think, this give an error like this **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\xampp\htdocs\new.php on line 3**

Comment: @Sant it was my mistake. Try now please

Comment: 0? it is returning zero when echoing **$version** while I'm using Google Chrome 14.0.835.202

Comment: Ok, I have browsercap.ini file up and running but i still get version 0

Comment: @Santosh if problem still unsolved you can ask another question posting the content of `$browser`

Answer (score 2):

Your only chance is to grab the `User-Agent` from the `$_SERVER` array. And there is no rule that forces a browser to include its version.

Answer (score 2):

A google search for 'php browser version detection' return [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) as the first result.  Please search before posting.

Comment: I know, I'm a kid in PHP can you give me a running example?

Comment: There's an example in the linked page.  Look at example #1.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [PPK's JavaScript-based browser detection code](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) to be very reliable.