# Determining browser type in server side code (PHP)

Tags: php, internet-explorer, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine Browser’s Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967008/determine-browsers-version)

I want to determine the browser type in the server code.

As it is, I am spending too much time hacking the **HTML/CSS** to get the site to display consistently across all browsers. The only browser in which the site is rendered differently (incorrectly), is IE, so I want to notify the users so that they understand why the pages are not as they would expect.

To this end, I am only interested in detecting requests from IE, so that I can inform IE users that the site is best viewed using another web browser.

I believe that the browser type is sent in one of the HTTP headers as part of the GET request. I am thinking of using this in my logic. Is there a better way?

A code snippet will be very useful. something along the lines of:

```
<?php
 $flag = $_GET(SOME_VARIABLE); // check if it is ANY IE version
?>
```

Comment: [`get_browser()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Comment: Why has this been marked down?. If you mark a question down, at least, have the courtesy to explain your action, so that (if valid), it prevents similar questions from being asked again.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter is not pleased that you don't fully support IE ;) In all seriousness though, browser detection is a pretty basic standard thing that web developers need to know about. There is loads of information on the web (including [so]) dealing with browser detection. Perhaps next time you should do a quick search before - you might find that someone else has already asked this question and already received some great answers :)

Comment: Those "best viewed in XXX" is just a bad excuse nowadays; it belongs in the previous decade.

Comment: @jack: In an ideal, world, that would be true. Unfortunately, there are still many people out there using IE8 (and earlier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look on $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] :)

Comment: It should be HTTP_USER_AGENT if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: This could be what I'm looking for. I will accept this answer as soon as the site allows me to do so (another 5 mins or so).

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [`get_browser`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function should be perfect for you -

> **get_browser** - Tells what the user's browser is capable of
>
> **return values** - The information is returned in an object or an array which will contain various data elements representing, for instance, the browser's major and minor version numbers and ID string; TRUE/FALSE values for features such as frames, JavaScript, and cookies; and so forth.

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
```

This function can return an array containing much information about the users browser

```
Array
(
    ...
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    ...
)
```

Comment: It should be noted that for `get_browser()` to work, you need to install and keep up to date `browscap.ini`.

Comment: Wow, I never came across this function before. Seems like what I need. I am not sure about browscap.ini though - which sounds like an extra dependency, which I am not too keen on ..

Comment: @hom - For simply detecting IE versions you should be fine (and it should already work on most default setups). You'd need to update it should there be any changes in the features of the browsers and you want to detect a certain capability...

Answer (score 1):

The internet is full of functions for browser detection

```
   function detect_ie(){
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
         (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false)){
           return true;
        }else{
           return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna be more specific you can try.

```
function getBrowser()
    {
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $bname = 'Unknown';
        $platform = 'Unknown';
        $version= "";
        if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent))
        {
            $platform = 'linux';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent))
        {
            $platform = 'mac';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent))
        {
            $platform = 'windows';
        }

        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
            $ub = "MSIE";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
            $ub = "Firefox";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Google Chrome';
            $ub = "Chrome";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Apple Safari';
            $ub = "Safari";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Opera';
            $ub = "Opera";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Netscape';
            $ub = "Netscape";
        }

        $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
        $pattern = '#(?' . join('|', $known) .')[/ ]+(?[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
        if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches))
        {

        }
        $i = count($matches['browser']);
        if ($i != 1)
        {
            if (strripos($u_agent,"Version")  $u_agent,
            'name'      => $bname,
            'version'   => $version,
            'platform'  => $platform,
            'pattern'    => $pattern
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do the [trick](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), but you should also just do it client side with JavaScript.