# $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] giving me MSIE7 instead of MSIE11

Tags: php, internet-explorer, browser

I am trying to use `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` to find a users browser and version.

Although when I use it with IE11 I get the following:

```
 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; 
    Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; 
    .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
```

I thought it might be something to do with compatibility mode, but it doesn't seem to be on. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure compatibility mode is not on ? As a side remark, be carefull what you do after detection, this method is far from accurate or secure.

Comment: Apparently this is the UA string for IE11 so it looks like there's something misconfigured on your end: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/03/27/internet-explorer-11s-user-agent-string-what-does-it-mean/

Comment: The original poster's sample *is* the Compatibility View setting for the IE11 User-Agent string. Warning: The nczonline.net post is outdated and does not have the current (non-Compat) UA String for IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
$browser = get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

This will output as a array and you can get the proper list of using browser by `print_r($browser);`.

see this: [Determine Browser's Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967008/determine-browsers-version)

Comment: As a note - `In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on your system.`

Comment: get_browser(); requires the browscap.ini file to be presented in the php configuration :)

Comment: I have tried the get_browser method, which works on chrome fine but I get the following for IE11:
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => §^.*$§
    [browser_name_pattern] => *
    [comment] => Default Browser
    [browser] => Default Browser
    [version] => 0
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 0
    [platform] => unknown
    [platform_version] => unknown
    [alpha] => 
    [beta] =>
    [win16] => 
    [win32] =>
    [win64] =>
    [frames] =>
    [iframes] =>
    [tables] => 
    [cookies] => 
    [javascript] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javaapplets] =>
    [activexcontrols] =>
)