# Reliable way to detect browser , version and plattfom in php

Tags: javascript, php, browser, owasp

I have been looking for a reliable way to have (at least the less obscure ones) :

1. the name of the browser
2. the version
3. and the platform (OS) it is on
4. maybe more information but the 3 info above are enough.

I want to display a custom content according to these information, example :

> If the user wants to know how to clear the cookies on his browser.
>   Let's say i have many contents already available for many browser.
>   versions And i want to load the appropriate content automatically

**Is there a way not involving Javascript to get these values?**

I have use cases where the browser is not found or inaccurate. So i would like to have the most reliable solution.

Here are 2 websites that does exactly what i need :

1. [www.whatismybrowser.com](http://www.whatismybrowser.com/) (contacted the owner to know how to do it in PHP)
2. [HawkBrowser](http://www.cyscape.com/showbrow.aspx) Really exhaustive test , not free

Other link with partial solutions:

1. [upgrademybrowser.org](http://updatemybrowser.org/) using the old browsercap of Aug 2012 ([source](https://github.com/hongaar/updatemybrowser))
2. Google's [www.whatbrowser.org](http://www.whatbrowser.org/)

Spent many days trying, seaching, but to no success. I found many hints from Stackoverflow community:

1. [browsercap](http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/) with [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)(). the project was discontinued  (for now 8 Aug. 2012) and doesn't detect some modern popular handheld device.
2. Javascript detect feature approach : [Modernirz](http://modernizr.com/). Not good approach for what i want to do, to long and will have to be updated often.
3. [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) Not good enough not enough possibility.
4. [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) javascript and not accurate with mobile for now and would prefer PHP version.

Other useful links :

1. [Stakoverflow Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php)
2. [Stackoverflow Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142030/any-php-code-to-detect-the-browser-with-version-and-operating-system)
3. [PHP mobile Detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)
4. [PIWIK](http://piwik.org/) analytic reports

**EDIT 1**
So far i have tested the answers  and comments. These solutions are very satisfying:

- **[PHP mobile detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)** the last version is really good, if you are using this it would be good to give the client the form in the example so they can contribute to the project. (thanks to @Pekka)
- **[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/php_index.php)** less recent but very good also. (thanks to @Ian Roberts)

  **EDIT 2**
  PHP mobile detect uses WURFL

**UPDATE**

Make sure that the header you receive are not modified by any other library.

For example some security libraries like **[OWASP PhpSec](https://github.com/OWASP/phpsec)** ***[ABANDONED]*** change the header structure into a custom object and  **[PHP mobile detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)** doesn't have access to all the information it needs anymore

For those of you using **[OWASP PhpSec](https://github.com/OWASP/phpsec)** ***[ABANDONED]*** the **http library** is modifying the global header object structure. (December 2013) So if you have issues just use **[PHP mobile detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)** before you include any **[OWASP PhpSec](https://github.com/OWASP/phpsec)** class using the **http library**

Comment: +1 for effort, but why is PHP mobile detect not working for you?

Comment: You won't get a **reliable** way to detect the browser. You could check the user agent which can be edited in most browsers or you could check for various capabilities of the browser.

Comment: @Pekka I just downloaded the dev version since you pointed that out and i am testing it right now. I was using an old version This is exactly what i needed. I will add a submission  form to encourage this. Please put it as an answer so i can choose it. Thx

Comment: @BenjaminPaap yes unfortunately that is true. I was looking for a solution that was maintained since  browsercap is suspended for now. Just like Pekka said PHP mobile detect works efficiently enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/php_index.php)? Its main aim is to classify mobile device browsers but it claims to have a mode that identifies desktop ones too.

Comment: Will try it and compare with the new PHP mobile Detect

Answer (score 0):

The Browser info in PHP you get from get_browser()

so you can use A ajax call to the PHP site, provides information about the user agent

e.g.

PHP

```
$info = get_browser(null, true);
echo json_encode($info);
```

The Array provided by get_browser looks like

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

This of course isn't a reliable solution because you can change your browser string as you want.

Comment: The values itself are from PHP, so you can use the PHP array/JSON in you php/html template or parse it to another template engine. The php only solution works also if javascript is disabled

Comment: Using ajax to get the browser from PHP is not a good solution, remove that and stick with `get_browser`, which in newer versions of PHP is a good way to sniff for browsers, if you have an update browsecap.ini file of course (which could be a problem these days). Then again, this is already outlined a lot better in the question ?