# detect the operating system using php

Tags: php

am writing a command line app using php, o need to automatically detect the os, so far i have the following code for detectOS method

```
public function detectOS() 
{
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    // is it linux?
    if(preg_match('/linux/i', $user_agent))
    {
        $this->env = new Linux;
        return $this->env;
    }

    // is it windows?
    if(preg_match('/windows/i', $user_agent))
    {
        $this->env = new Windows;
        return $this->env;
    }

    // is it mac
    if(preg_match('/mac/i', $user_agent))
    {
        $this->env = new Mac;
        return $this->env;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and this is the test am using for that method

```
// -------------------------------------------------- detectOS
public function testOsIsLinux()
{
    $os = new OS($this->path);
    $env_name = $os->detectOS();

    $this->assertInstanceOf('Linux', $os->env);
}
```

when i run the test i get the following error

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT
```

so i guess that i need a native php function to detect the os am on.

any ideas, or i just implement it in python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142030/any-php-code-to-detect-the-browser-with-version-and-operating-system?rq=1

Comment: its a command line app, get_browser is not working because am not running any server, please read the my question first, i already tell that HTTP_USER_AGENT is an undefined index.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to detect OS?

Comment: because i need to do some system stuff, and write custom class for each system.

Comment: Here you have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482260/how-to-get-the-os-on-which-php-is-running

Comment: The question was answered before, indeed, but it is a duplicate of a different question. The correct one is the one provided by mark91.

Comment: tnx @mark91, that was what am looking for.